# Trial Periods days

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, terms-of-service

I have subscribed to a 30 days' trial period product online on 8th May 2021 in the afternoon. The contract says that after 30 days, payment will be taken. I thought I can cancel today (7th June 2021) in the afternoon, so 30 days will not exceed. But the company has charged me today morning.

Is there anyway I can request the company for the refund based on the subscribed time? Or is the 30 days based on calendar days?

Comment: What does the contract actually say about the "30-day trial".

Comment: If you were the company, what would you put in the small print to maximise your profit? I’d make sure to count whole days, and 8th May to 7th June inclusive is 31 days.

Comment: Knowing which jurisdiction (country, province, state etc) you're in may assist

Comment: @Dale M it says after 30 days, the payment will be taken.

Comment: @Rock Ape its for UK